Aligning conditions in pairs of cases
Is there any way to align the conditions in more than one cases environment? (the "u=0"/"u>0" below)
$$\begin{aligned}
x_1 &= \begin{cases}Z & u = 0 \\ 
                    Z + 1 & u > 0
       \end{cases} \\
x_2 &= \begin{cases}WXYZ & u = 0 \\ 
                    WXYZ + 1 & u > 0
       \end{cases} \\
\end{aligned}$$


